# Assertion error for testing Junit with reactive WebTestClient Status Expected :201 Actual :404

Tags: reactive-programming, junit5, webtestclient

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebFluxTest(controllers = EventsControllerTest.class)
class EventsControllerTest {
    @MockBean
    UserRepo repo;
    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webClient;

```
@Test
void testAssignUserRoles() {
    UserInfo user = new UserInfo();
    user.setId(Long.valueOf(1));
    user.setFirstname("Test");
    user.setLastname("Test2");
    user.setActiveuser(true);
    user.setEmailid("tet@test.com");
    user.setRolename("test");
    user.setUserpassword("test");
    Mockito.when(repo.save(user)).thenReturn(Mono.just(user));
    webClient.post().uri("/assignRoles").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(user)).exchange().expectStatus().isCreated();
    Mockito.verify(repo, times(1)).save(user);
}
```

**Controller**
   @RestController 
public class EventsController {
    @Autowired
    UserInfoRepository userInfoRepository;

```
@PostMapping(value = "/saveRole")
public Mono<UserInfo> assignUserRoles(@RequestBody UserInfo userInfo) {
    return userInfoRepository.save(userInfo).log();
}
```

Comment: Please fix code formatting to include annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Access URI should match value attribute of `@PostMapping`: `saveRole`.

Comment: added for postmapping URI that matches on test class , java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<201 CREATED> but was:<404 NOT_FOUND>

Comment: > POST /assignRoles
> WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]
> Content-Type: [application/json]
> Content-Length: [147]
{"id":1,"rolename":"test","firstname":"Test","lastname":"Test2","userpassword":"test","emailid":"tet@test.com","employeeid":null,"activeuser":true}
< 404 NOT_FOUND Not Found
< Content-Type: [application/json]
< Content-Length: [137]
{"timestamp":"2020-04-24T06:39:15.504+0000","path":"/assignRoles","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":null,"requestId":"4c99c987"}
org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.ExchangeResult.assertWithDiagnostics(ExchangeResult.java:209)